# Product with special price should not applied for a discount in shopping cart using promotion rule

Tags: magento-enterprise, discount, promotions, special-price

I have made one promotion rule for shopping cart. If product has price $7.99 from specific category, will get fixed amount of discount $5. This promotion rule is not working well when some products from same category and had price $7.99 applied a special price of $0.99 or something else, got the fixed amount of discount of $5. By this that product sold at $0.

To fixed this issue , I tried the condition
if special price from that category product has value greater than 0.(if this is true, then discount shouldn't applied). but this condition fail when special price time period is over.
I also tried 'price in cart' condition. But it is not working.

Can anyone tell me what should be the condition, so special price product should not get discount in shopping cart ?

Answer (score 2):

Magento give the highest priority as follow :

1) Catalog price rules

2) Special price

3) Tier Prices

4) Group prices

And your promotion rule is applying on the base price of the product so magento use special price instead of your base price. I suggest you should use `Special Price From Date` and `Special Price to Date` instead of `Special price` so that magento will take care of your promotion rule for that period of time. Hope this will help you out.

Comment: Can you please tell me ,what purpose of "price in cart" condition, which section it target ?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me what should be the condition, so special price
>   product should not get discount in shopping cart ?

Not easily done, out-the-box. The main issue would be date ranges, from when/to special prices are valid. You'd need to constantly update the rule(s) with new date range values, or constantly update exclusion categories with invalid products, as dates change.

However, there IS a solution, but requires 3rd party (non free) module.

I have run into this issue plenty, and I use my own created [Dynamic Category Products](http://www.proxiblue.com.au/premium-modules/magento-dynamic-category-products.html) extension to create automated exclusion categories. Since they update automatically, the exclusion lists are always up-to-date.

Here is a small how-to, using the 3rd party module

Create a new category, which is not visible in menus or even enabled.
In that category, create a dynamic category rule which will pull in all products with discount - be it special price, or catalog rules, or both.

The rule will automatically consider date ranges, so only products valid on the day the category is saved (or automatically rebuild, daily by cron, at 00:00) will appear.

This then  solves the noted question you placed in comments:

> Can you please suggest any condition so that I do not need to change
>   the from/to dates condition everytime I apply new special price

as dates are taken into consideration.

[image]

You can then use this category as an exclusion list in your rules.
You can even flip this, and build categories of 'allowed' products, and then build rules to only action on the given category products.

Using the Dynamic Category Products extension, you can create many 'staging' categories, which is purely used for other processes (like discount rules/exports/feeds)

I know this is not a coding solution, but I feel this still answrs the question, just in case those down-vote nazi's attack this answer.

OP asked for a solution, this is one!

Answer (score 0):

You are able to limit the products that a promotion applies to with the Actions tab in `Shopping Cart Price Rules`.

I typically set it up as follows:

[image]

## Edit

If you're on a version of Magento that does not support the `is assigned` value for the attribute you will have to take two extra steps.

1. In the Attribute management panel under `Catalog > Manage Attributes` select the `special_from_date` attribute. Modify it to be included in promo rule conditions.

[image]
[image]

2. Then, in your Shopping Cart price rule you can set the date condition to be from a certain date, after a certain date; or even between two dates.

[image]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am using enterprise ver. 1.11.2.0. How do I get this section "Product Attribute Assigned".

Comment: This is not available in 1.11. You'd need to upgrade to 1.14. Use of Special Price equals or greater would be good enough for you.

Comment: Can you please suggest any condition so that I do not need to change the from/to dates condition everytime I apply new special price

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Can you please tell me ,what purpose of "price in cart" condition, which section it target ?

Comment: @philwinkle isn't the answer completely opposite to the question. I guess above rule will enable discounts on products with special prices. Correct me if i am confusing things